# Table body element overlaps thead element

Tags: html, css, browser

As shown in this demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/fixed-table-header-y4g13?file=/src/App.tsx

I've set the `thead` element to `transform: translateY` property to achieve the `sticky header` effect(I know you can use css property `sticky` but it will conflict with table scroll horzontically within wrapper element).

The weird thing is that when some table elements given some specific properties (e.g. `filter: hue-rotate` or `position: sticky` it will display on top of thead element no matter how you adjust the `z-index` of both elements.

Is this a browser bug? Found on both chrome

[image]

and safari

[image]

Answer (score 1):

z-index is relative to the nearest position context, so adding `z-index: 100` to your `th` elements will not position it relative to the same context as any `td` inside `tbody`.

Instead, add `position:relative` and `z-index: 1` to your `thead` to move the whole `thead` above the `tbody`.

[Forked sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fixed-table-header-forked-wwgdb)

Comment: hmm thanks for the answer, but in the forked sandbox the problem still persists. td element overlaping thead

Comment: Which td? cell-X-X? 15-5 (the blue one) is definitely appearing below the thead.

Comment: yeah `cell-15-5`. it has `filter:
                          "hue-rotate(85deg) saturate(80%) brightness(0.85)"` property and it overlaps thead element, which it shouldn't

Comment: What browser are you using? 15-5 is definitely below the thead for me on Chrome. [Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/zeA6QGE.png)

Comment: what? i'm using chrome Version 83.0.4103.116/ let me update the question with screenshot

Comment: Are you sure you're opening my sandbox? lol. I opened it on my Mac too just to be sure since I thought it might be an OS thing, but nope it's still underneath on my end.

Comment: yes what i open is exactly https://wwgdb.csb.app/ (also screenshots taken from this url) as you can see cell still on top of thead.